# Typescript inherit constructor param object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-class

```
import hospital from "./hospital.json";


class Hospital {
    constructor(public hospital) {
   
    }
    ...other_methods

}

const SampleHospital = new Hospital(hospital);
```

I have raw data which is hospital.json.

I decided to create a class for a hospital to add some methods to the hospital.

**The problem is**

When I want to access to hospital's field there will always be extra access `.hospital.`

`SampleHospital.hospital.contact`

I want to make it `SampleHospital.contact`.

Of course, I can add another public field.

But to create every public field for hospital object will require a lot of effort.

---

I tried

```
type THospital = typeof hospital ;
class Hospital implements THospital {
    constructor(hospital: THospital) {
        [...Object.keys(hospital)].forEach(key => this[key] = hospital[key])
    }
}
```

But the typescript didn't understand my field assignment.

[image]

It says fields are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop on all keys of parameter object and assign current object to parameter object value

```js
const hospital = {
  name: 'win',
  contact: 'test'
};

class Hospital {
  constructor(hospital) {
    [...Object.keys(hospital)].forEach(key => this[key] = hospital[key]);
  }
}

const SampleHospital = new Hospital(hospital);

console.log(SampleHospital.name);
```

In typescript you will have to say my type can have other property you have to use index signature for this  `[index: string]: any;`

```
const hospital = {
    name: 'win',
    contact: 'test'
  };
  
  class Hospital {
    [index: string]: any;
    constructor(hospital) {
      [...Object.keys(hospital)].forEach(key => this[key] = hospital[key]);
    }
  }
  
  const SampleHospital = new Hospital(hospital);
  
  console.log(SampleHospital.name);
```

Comment: Thanks but typescript's type is problem. 
couldn't get TypeScript's type support that way.

Comment: yes you could use index signature 
    `[index: string]: any;` i edit my reply to give you a sample